# What is the best way of managin my JAR API

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, project-management

Simple question. When I'm preparing jar library, let's say "mondule-one". Maven is building JAR: module-one-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar. Should I extract all my interfaces to module-one-api project, or just use some plugin to deal with it? And then I will get module-one-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar.

What is the best way? And where can I get more information about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way from point of view decoupling is to create a separate module like you already mentioned something like `module-one-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` which makes it simpler for others to use the API only and may be create a separate implementation (DI).

Comment: I have pushed my project to github: https://github.com/kirkor/tarnica-mountain -> what do You think about project structure?